# Unable to Grant User Privileges in Amazon RDS MySQL: Error Changing Account admin@%%

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Despite logging in as the 'admin' user with the correct password, I am unable to perform various administrative tasks or grant necessary privileges. This limitation prevents me from effectively managing the database. I can for example not grant the privilige "FILE", which enables me to load a file into my database.

I have already explored potential solutions such as:

Checking the account privileges: I verified that the 'admin' account does not have the necessary privileges to perform administrative tasks, including the 'GRANT OPTION' privilege.

Given this context, I am seeking guidance and potential solutions to grant the missing privileges to the 'admin' user in my Amazon RDS MySQL database. Any assistance, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the command “LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE” work on versions of MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench before 8.0.. This appears to have been done for security reason

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).